# How to merge two eloquent and load relationships

Tags: laravel, merge, eloquent

How can I merge two eloquent collections without losing any data and load relationship after that?

```php
//I have two collections

$e1=Colour::find(1,3,7);
$e2=Colour::find(31,33,88);
```

```php
//I need the following output

$merged=$e1->merge($e2)->load('relation');
```

When I performed the above merge, the first collection overwrites the second.

Please, give me a solution.

Comment: try with `$e1->combine($e2)->load('relation');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push elements of `$e2` to `$e1` collection then use `$e1` as you see fit.

```
foreach ($e2 as $e) {
    $e1->push($e);
}
$e1->load('relation');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Laravel Collections**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-put

Code Example:

```
$collection = collect(['value' => $e1->value]);

$collection->put('value', $e2->value);

$collection->all();
```

Comment: The code is just for example. But, merging two arrays will work with  Laravel Collection.